# materializeccs' chip.select is not working

Tags: jquery, materialize

I'm using this: http://materializecss.com/chips.html

And in the docs it says that you can add these events to your chips: `chip.add`, `chip.delete`, `chip.select`.

Delete and add works fine for me, but select doesn't. Am I doing something wrong here?

```
$('#my_chips_container')
    .on('chip.delete', function(e, chip) {
        console.log('just deleted one');
    })
    .on('chip.select', function(e, chip) {
        console.log('just selected one');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using sufficient versions of both jquery and materialize and are referenced once and only once.

I am not running into any problems running your code.
http://codepen.io/bruns/pen/vyXZYK?editors=1111

I initiated my container as `<div id='my_chips_container'></div>`